# Deprecation issue when running test: Comparable#== will no more rescue exceptions of #<=>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I run the specs, I get the following errors:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:26: warning: Comparable#== will no more rescue exceptions of #<=> in the next release.
.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:26: warning: Return nil in #<=> if the comparison is inappropriate or avoid such comparison.
```

The only place I <=> is in one of my models:

```
class PostCategory
  CONTEXTS = %w(regular)

  module Collections
    def all
      @all ||= AppConfig.post_categories.
       map { |c| new(c) }.
       sort
    end

    def in_context(context)
      @all.select { |e| e.in_context?(context) }
    end
  end

  extend Collections

  include Comparable

  attr_reader :name, :image_id

  def initialize(hash)
    @name          = hash.fetch('name')
    @image_id      = hash.fetch('image_id')
    @contexts      = hash.fetch('contexts', CONTEXTS)
  end

  def <=>(other) 
    @name <=> other.name
  end
end
```

I tried adding nil below after "def <=>(other)" but creates a problem for sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning occurs due to a change you can see discussed in [this Ruby issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7688). The gist of it is this: When a class includes Comparable and its `==` method is called, `Comparable#==` in turn calls the `<=>` method. In versions of Ruby so far, if `<=>` raised an error, `==` would swallow the error and return `false`. This is good because developers don't expect `==` to raise an error, but it's bad because it can hide problems with `<=>`. In future versions, `==` will no longer swallow errors raised by `<=>`, hence the warning.

If you look at the [Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/73521d586981279a99d3ba038d62e2414125df7a/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb#L26) on the line mentioned in your stack trace you can see where the error is coming from:

```
define_callbacks :validation,
                 terminator: ->(_,result) { result == false },
                 # ...
```

In your case, `result` is an instance of your PostCategory class. When the second line above calls `result == false`, your `<=>` method calls `false.name`, which raises an error (because `false` doesn't respond to `name`).

The solution is to do as the [Comparable docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Comparable.html) say:

> If the other object is not comparable then the `<=>` operator should return `nil`.

Amend your method like this:

```
def <=>(other)
  return unless other.respond_to?(:name)
  @name <=> other.name
end
```

Or, if you want instances of PostCategory to be comparable only to other instances of PostCategory (as opposed to anything that responds to `name`):

```
def <=>(other)
  return unless other.is_a?(self.class)
  @name <=> other.name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough details to diagnose the problem precisely, but below are two hints that should help you to resolve an issue.

• The warning tells you that there was an exception in `<=>` rescued by the engine. OK, to avoid it we should firstly understand what it is:

```
def <=>(other) 
  @name <=> other.name
rescue => e
  puts e.inspect # or even e.backtrace
end
```

• Now, when you know what the exact problem is, you might handle it gracefully:

```
def <=>(other) 
  return nil unless @name.is_a?(String) && other.name.is_a?(String)
  @name <=> other.name
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @mudasobwa and I apologize for not providing more info.  When I run `rescue => e`, I get `undefined method 'name' for false:FalseClass`. Is the fix the one mentioned below (`return unless other.respond_to?(:name)`) as that seems to work?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Unless you want to define any specific behaviour when comparing your strings against `false`, which is unlikely.